# Buttons stop working when UserControl is added to page

Tags: asp.net, button, user-controls, postback

I have a content page with a `UserControl`. When the `UserControl` is added to the page, all of the buttons, including buttons in the master page, stop working. If I remove the `UserControl` the buttons start working again. By not working, I mean if you click them nothing happens at all, no postback. Some buttons still work, such as the `GridView` header labels which sort the columns. These cause postback, but nothing else.

The only elements in the `UserControl` are a `fieldset` containing a html `label`, containing a `RequiredFieldValidator` and a `TextBox`.

This solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716465/dropdownlist-onselectedindexchanged-event-stops-working-when-seemingly-unrelated) mentions solving a similar problem by including a `!isPostBack` check to the `Page_Load`, but what is included? My `UserControl` `Page_Load` event is currently empty.

### Update

User Control .ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="StaffEditFields.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="StaffEditFields" %>
<fieldset>
    <label>
        Username
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfdUser" runat="server" Display="Static"
            ControlToValidate="txtUser" />
            <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server" CssClass="fvBox" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' />
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

### Update 2

Removed the `fieldset` and nothing changed, but when I removed the `RequiredFieldValidator` the page began to function normally. Now I need to ask how to keep the `RequiredFieldValidator` and allow the `UserControl` to function properly?

Comment: Have you attached a debugger? It may be that there is a Javascript issue.

Comment: Can you post the content of the usercontrol here or is it too large? I'd guess the cause is a badly formed tag in the control.

Comment: Have you tried removing everything from the user control except for some dummy text to see if it still breaks the page? Just to narrow down what's happening. Alternatively, is there another control with the same ID elsewhere on the page you're adding this usercontrol to? You might be unknowingly causing ID conflict. And also, your validator has no ID, you should add one.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton The page works when the `UserControl` is just dummy text. So that means it's a problem with my elements in the `UserControl`? Would it be a problem if I used the same `UserControl` multiple times in a page? with different ID's for each? I'm using this control so I don't have to copy my `FormView` template multiple times whenever I alter it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem is the `RequiredFieldValidator` is not set to validate to any specific button, therefore it will try to validate on ANY button click on the page. I also failed to set any button to `CausesValidation="true"`.

The solution is then to set a validation group for the `RequiredFieldValidator` and set a button inside or outside the `UserControl` to `CausesValidation="true"` and `ValidationGroup=[group]`.